# Discord.js@14.6 cant create channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Ahhhhh I am going insane. I have asked many questions about creating channels, but i still dont manage to understand, wtf am i doing wrong????
This is the code i am using:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, messageLink, InteractionResponseType, ChannelType } = require('discord.js');
const logger = require('winston');
const discord = require("discord.js");
const { EmbedBuilder, SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildEmojisAndStickers,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
    ],
});
//
const fs = require("node:fs");
const guild = bot.guilds.cache.get("1037081018500399154");
const path = require("node:path");
const token = "you tought"
//text
bot.on('ready', () => { // when the bot is ready and online
    console.log('bot is now online!')
    bot.user.setActivity("Servers");
});



  guild.channels.create({
    name: "hello",
    type: ChannelType.GuildText,
    // your permission overwrites or other options here
});
```

It throws this msg everytime i start my bot

`Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channels')`

Pleas help me, i am going insane ngl. And yes, i have read the docs.

{Edit : There is usually more code, but i have just deleted the code as of now}

Comment: You can't grab the `guild` outside of an event listener because the bot is not yet logged in at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in a ready event. It should be like this:

```
bot.on("ready" , () => {
    const guild = bot.guilds.cache.get("1037081018500399154");
    guild.channels.create({
        name: "hello",
        type: ChannelType.GuildText,
        // your permission overwrites or other options here
    });
});
```

I hope to be of help to you.